# Pull max for multiple identical ID's in Excel

Tags: excel

If I have a situation where:

```
Column A    Column B
21202       100
21202       400
30021       503
30021       922
```

And I wanted to make a column that only pulled the maximum for each identical Column A number such as:

```
Column A    Column B
21202       400
30021       922
```

Would I do so by using vlookup?

Comment: You certainly _can_.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I'm assuming your two tables are in columns `A` and `B` of two different sheets.

In cell B2 of the second sheet, enter: `=MAX(IF(Sheet1!A1:A200=A2,B1:B200))` as an array formula (i.e. instead of hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the formula, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Make sure to replace `Sheet1` with the name of your first sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A non CSE formula; entered normally:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet1!B1:B100/(Sheet1!A1:A100 = A2),1)
```

Again ensure that the reference of `Sheet1` is to the sheet on which the data resides.

Comment: With Office 365 also [`MAXIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXIFS-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is possible ;)